# PHP loop over every second element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data and in this array there is another array for products. And I want to loop over every item of the product array and execute a specific function (no problem with this), but for every second item I want to execute a different function.

The Array looks like this:

*demoData.php*

```
<?php
return array(
  'documentInfo' => array(
      "demoSubject",
      "demoTitel",
      "demoCreator",
      "demoAuthor",
      "demoKeywords",
  ),
  'products' => array(
     "product one",
     "product two",
     "product three",
     "product four",
     "product five",
  )
);
?>
```

The function I want to execute for every second array item is the following (PDFlib textflow function with bold text):

```
$tf = $p->add_textflow($tf, /** item of $products */ . " ", $optlistMedium);
```

And for the other items I want to execute the following function (it's the same function generally speaking, but with normal text):

```
$tf = $p->add_textflow($tf, /** item of $products */ . " ", $optlistNormal);
```

If I understand this correct I can do it with a foreach loop for products and then in this foreach loop I put an if statement, am I correct? Something like this:

```
foreach($array['products'] as $products) {
  if(/** Every second array item */) {
     /** Execute function for bold text */
  } else {
     /** Execute function for normal text */
  }
}
```

Though I don't really understand how I can get it working, so that the if statement gets every second element of the array. Maybe someone can help me with this.

Comment: (Please try and tag more appropriately. Your actual problem here has little to do with `pdf` and `pdflib` - your question is not about those, you would have struggled with the same issue if you f.e. simply tried to output the data as a list or table in HTML, and apply the same alternating formatting to the items in there.)

Comment: for every odd index, you run your function and for every even index you don't; set a counter and check if the counter is odd or even by using mod function; ($counter % 2 == 0) is even and else is odd

Comment: @CBroe oh yeah sorry, I thought because I'm working with pdflib the tags would be useful. And the answer you suggested does kinda answer this, but the problem I'm having is that I don't understand how to output the array the right way. If I write add_textflow($tf, $products, $optlistMedium) and add_textflow($tf, $products, $optlistNormal) it outputs each array item twice

Comment: Well put one of those into the `if` branch, and the other into the `else` branch.

Comment: @CBroe That's what I did, but the problem was elsewhere. I had the same output still outside of the foreach (but in the same textflow), that's why it gave pout those items twice. But thank you for helping me!